# Save the current selection as HTML in Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

In Excel, when saving a workbook to an HTML file, one has the choice to save the entire workbook or the current selection only.

How can one programmatically perform the latter using Python `win32com` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I found:

```py
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants

excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
selection = excel.Selection
worksheet = selection.Parent
workbook = worksheet.Parent
publish_object = workbook.PublishObjects.Add(
    constants.xlSourceRange,
    Filename=r'C:\absolute\path\to\file.html',
    Sheet=worksheet.Name,
    Source=selection.Address,
    HtmlType=constants.xlHtmlStatic
)
publish_object.Publish(True)
```

Not sure if it is the best way but it works. See [`Application.Selection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.application.selection),  [`PublishObjects.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.publishobjects.add) and [`PublishObject.Publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.publishobject.publish) for additional options (saving Pivot Tables, Charts, etc).